# Custom list based on Content type Page Layout in Sharepoint online

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I have a content type that extends Page Layout (*0x01010007FF3E057FA8AB4AA42FCB67B453FFC100E214EEE741181F4E9F7ACC43278EE811*). 
Now I try to make a custom list that uses that content type. I do Settings - >Advanced settings - > Allow management of content types, Yes. And then I try to add from existing site content types, and I can't find it there. 
Is it not possible to use a Content Type that extends Page Layout in a custom list? If so, do I have to create a view under pages instead? 

Best regards
Olof

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that certain content types are constrained to certain list types.

The Page Layout content type inherits from the Document content type. You can use Document content types in a Document Library, but not in a custom list.